# Is it possible to make 32 bit gRPC and protobuf?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Is it possible to **make** [this library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) as 32bit? By default, this builds as 64bit.
How can i include this library in my 32bit application?

Comment: All you have to do to compile for 32bit (assuming you have appropriate 32bit libraries etc. available) with GCC is add the `-m32` option to your compile and link lines.

Comment: @MadScientist **export CFLAGS=-m32** ?

Comment: There's no way to know the right way to do it other than by reading the makefile or asking the developer of the makefile.  Based on the briefest look at the makefile you probably need to set all the variables `EXTRA_CFLAGS`, `EXTRA_CXXFLAGS`, and `EXTRA_LDFLAGS`

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough information to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's ways to cross-compile libraries, but it's usually easier to build from a 32 bit system if you don't know how. You can debootstrap a 32 bit userspace on your own system and use chroot to access it.

https://jblevins.org/log/ubuntu-chroot

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible. Actually, one of gRPC's continuous tests is testing that the 32bit build works well.

We are using this 32bit dockerfile to build:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5059fd195753d0c18e51efa930aebd7e0461ed51/tools/dockerfile/test/cxx_jessie_x86/Dockerfile

You can also crosscompile as others are mentioning above. You're not mentioning if you are building on linux, windows or macos, so I assumed you're on linux but building a 32bit grpc is possible on windows and macos too (and perhaps easier than on linux).